# Hannan–Quinn information criterion and Kashyap information criterion (KIC)

Tags: model-selection, aic, intuition, fisher-information

As we may know, the capacity of a model to overfit could easily increase by an increase in the complexity of that model (take complexity roughly as a number of parameters). To handle this problem, there are some model selection criteria that are suggested by statisticians. As described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection#:%7E:text=Below%20is%20a%20list%20of,extent%20approximates%20the%20Bayes%20factor),

The AIC and BIC are both methods of assessing model fit penalized for the number of estimated parameters.

- [Hannan–Quinn information criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannan%E2%80%93Quinn_information_criterion), an alternative to the Akaike and Bayesian criteria
- [Kashyap information criterion (KIC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashyap_information_criterion) is a powerful alternative to AIC and BIC because KIC uses the Fisher information matrix

I am wondering if anyone used methods like Hannan–Quinn information criterion and Kashyap information criterion (KIC).

I am really having trouble understanding the intuition behind KIC. I mean how KIC is using Fisher information matrix and how these methods are used for Model Selection